# Unable to index file BUILD

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm trying to move over a project from Maven into Gradle, however after forking and moving things around to get it to build I'm unable to commit my changes.

I'm getting this error every time:

```
Error:error: unable to index file BUILD
fatal: updating files failed
 during executing git commit --amend --only -F /private/var/folders/3k/880djfp91m55jrzy3tc06n3c0000zk/T/git-commit-msg-7502516589637349407.txt -- external/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml external/appcompat/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-my-rMM/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/values-es/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-ta-rIN/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/values/config.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark.png external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_item_background_holo_light.xml assets/internal_web/right.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_spinner_ab_disabled_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png src/info/guardianproject/browser/CookieManagerDataStore.java external/appcompat/res/layout/abc_activity_chooser_view.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_btn_check_material.xml external/appcompat/README.txt external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_commit_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_tab_selected_focused_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_textfield_searchview_right_holo_dark.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/values-eu-rES/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_light.png res/drawable/ic_menu_back.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png market/orwebfeatures1024x500.png res/drawable/ic_menu_info_details.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_stacked_transparent_dark_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-iw/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-v11/styles_base.xml external/appcompat/res/values-lo-rLA/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_tab_selected_pressed_holo.9.png BUILD external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png build.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_light_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/values-mk-rMK/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_go_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_solid_dark_holo.9.png src/info/guardianproject/browser/AnonProxy.java external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png res/values-nb-rNO/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha.png res/drawable/icon_orweb.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light.png res/values-nl/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png res/values/style.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_cab_background_bottom_holo_dark.9.png .tx/config external/appcompat/res/values-w360dp/dimens.xml external/appcompat/res/values/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/values-sv/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_textfield_search_default_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/layout/abc_action_bar_tabbar.xml external/appcompat/res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png .gitattributes src/info/guardianproject/browser/ClearCachePreference.java external/appcompat/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_commit_search_api_holo_dark.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_search.png external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml external/appcompat/res/values-port/bools.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png res/layout/dialog_addsite.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_voice_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/values-bn-rBD/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_spinner_ab_default_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/values/bools.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_voice_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png AndroidManifest.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_textfield_searchview_holo_dark.xml external/appcompat/res/values-en-rIN/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_cab_background_bottom_holo_light.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_solid_dark_holo.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml external/appcompat/res/values-hy-rAM/strings.xml res/drawable/ic_menu_save.png external/appcompat/res/values-w720dp/bools.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_spinner_ab_disabled_holo_light.9.png src/info/guardianproject/browser/Utils.java external/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_commit_search_api_holo_light.png external/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/values-th/strings.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/layout/abc_action_bar_up_container.xml external/appcompat/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png external/appcompat/res/values-fr/strings.xml res/values/styles.xml res/drawable/ic_btn_search_go.png res/drawable/ic_dialog_browser_certificate_secure.png
```

Quite long as you can tell, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What command did you run? I.e. was it `git commit --amend` that you just ran?